# Let us sort tags in User pages by most recent date active

Tags: feature-request, tags

Currently, while viewing a user's page, we can view their tags and sort by **Votes** or by **Name**. I am requesting that we be given the ability to sort by date most recently active.

Ex 1: If I answered one question today, and it was on a question tagged [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) and [html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html), then those two tags would be at the front (or top) of the list while sorted by  **Date Active** (or however you want to call it). Of course, earning points isn't necessary. If I have yet to receive any upvotes, that should *still* move the appropriate tags to the front of the list.

The benefit this has is that it gives us an additional way to measure how we (or other users) are lately spending our time answering questions at Stack Overflow, rather than having to go through our most recent questions one by one and look at each question's tags.

There are probably other benefits to users and to Stack Overflow's personal metrics measuring that I haven't thought of.

Comment: Your question says "most recently earned", but it sounds like you actually want "most recently active"?

Comment: @BenVoigt Yes, most recently earned means "most recently earned [points in]" here. "Active" is fine as a substitute word.

Comment: "Questions" tab shows the tags too,  and you can order it by "newest". Maybe including tags to "Answers" tab too would do what you are after?

Comment: @Teemu In a round-about way, it probably would, but I would much rather see the option achieved within the Tags tab, where you would logically think to go to sort your Tags one of various ways.

Comment: The problem is, that tags don't have "Date" property (unless a creation date), you would need a massive cross-searching throughout  the database to connect a tag to an "active date" via questions/answers. Even then it's difficult to order them, since the same tag would gain several dates.

Comment: @Teemu I don't think it would be massive. A simple joining of the tags table and the posts table in the database via a query. Questions already have dates and tags, it shouldn't be too difficult to find whether a given user posted an answer there and then sort by date.